# Is it possible to visualize Bellman-Ford Algorithm with Path Finding / Maze Solver

Tags: algorithm, path-finding, bellman-ford

Is it possible? I don't know how to do it, can you give me ideas? I want to do something like this:

Example: A* Search

[image: 1]

Thank you!

Comment: Please, load the image directly from your computer instead of putting links so that we can be sure it's not a CSRF attack

Comment: About the question, the thing is that in Bellman Ford algorithm you don't have the concepts of target node, visited node, frontier node, path node, wall node. You rather do V iterations (where V is the number of vertices) and relax all the edges of the graph at each iteration. In the end, you get all shortest paths from a given vertex.

Comment: What you can do is show the relaxed edges at each iteration (maybe by coloring with the same color the two vertices of a relaxed edge). This way you can see the evolution of the algorithm through the graph.

Comment: There're quite a few - the one that I posted is pretty good, it covers the basics - check it out.

Comment: You're welcome. If you already know what is the final result before the simulation, an idea is to use a gradient of colors to indicate how close a relaxed edge is from the solution